# VHDL clock divider flips between 0 and X every clk cycle

Tags: vhdl, clock, digital-design

I'm starting out trying to learn VHDL after doing a little bit of Verilog.

This is my attempt at creating a clock divider: 
(largely taken from [Making a clock divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708301/making-a-clock-divider))

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity clock_192 is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clr : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk_out : out STD_LOGIC);
end clock_192;

architecture Behavioral of clock_192 is
signal q : std_logic_vector (23 downto 0);
begin
    clk_out <= q(23);
    process(clk,clr)
    begin
        if clr = '1' then
            q <= "000000000000000000000000";
        elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
            q <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(q)+1);
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

And here is the test bench I'm using:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY test_clock_192 IS
END test_clock_192;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test_clock_192 IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT clock_192
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         clr : IN  std_logic;
         clk_out : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal clr : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal clk_out : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;
   constant clk_out_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: clock_192 PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          clr => clr,
          clk_out => clk_out
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;

   clk_out_process :process
   begin
        clk_out <= '0';
        wait for clk_out_period/2;
        clk_out <= '1';
        wait for clk_out_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
        clr <= '1';
      wait for 97 ns;   
        clr <= '0';

      wait for clk_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

The trouble is my clk_out signal keeps flipping between 0 and X with every cycle of clk. As seen here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCvWi.png]

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

EDIT: 
To fix the problem I had to change my test bench to look like this:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY test_clock_192 IS
END test_clock_192;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test_clock_192 IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT clock_192
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         clr : IN  std_logic;
         clk_out : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal clr : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal clk_out : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;
   constant clk_out_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: clock_192 PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          clr => clr,
          clk_out => clk_out
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
        clr <= '1';
      wait for 97 ns;   
        clr <= '0';

      wait for clk_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: There are a few ways to simplify the clock divider process : (1) use the `rising_edge(clk)` function instead of `clk'event and clk='1'` (2) use types rather than fighting them : make `q` unsigned, then the clocked line simplifies to `q <= q + 1;` (3) to clear `q` use `q <= (others => '0');` it saves counting bits, and still works if you change the size of `q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test bench drives the `clk_out` signal both from the `uut` instance and the `clk_out_process` process, and this makes the resolution function for the `std_logic` take effect.

When both sources drive `'0'` then the resulting `clk_out` value will be `'0'`, but if one source drives `'0'` and the other drives `'1'` then the resolution function will return `'X'`, as you see.

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856618/2352082) for some description of "VHDL resolution function", or try google it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed the problem. Also this is the first time I've heard of the VHDL resolution function and I appreciate the link.

Comment: Checks out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL#Further_reading for some good learning material; can recommend "The Designer's Guide to VHDL".